# Large semigroups of real matrices with real eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, semigroups

There are a bunch of matrix properties that ensure that all the eigenvalues are real, chief among them being symmetric.  However, I cannot find nontrivial examples of *semigroups* (under any kind of product) of matrices all with real eigenvalues.  Examples include, I believe:

- Semigroup under multiplication generated by some matrices (with real eigenvalues) that commute.
- Semigroup under multiplication generated by a symmetric matrix and a symmetric positive definite matrix.

**Question:** Is there a nontrivial semigroup of real matrices, all with real eigenvalues, that does not fall in these two examples?

Answer (score 1):

What about upper triangular matrices (with real diagonal entries)?